# AngularJS - ng-include template behaves differently

Tags: angularjs

I'm struggling with understanding why ng-include template seems to break my angular application.

I have some ui bootstrap tab issues with multiple controllers and went with this design which works (note I cannot use the built in tab switching across multiple controllers, so it is hidden):
https://plnkr.co/edit/hCCVFt58OXztZDQtxGIS?p=preview

However, simply moving the nav section to a template breaks the tab switching:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Lbh2Pw2wiZAS6oZTwX47?p=preview

The variable 'active_tab' seems to update correctly... but I'm guessing the scope changes when it is in the template?

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
        </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="navCollapsed">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{active: active_tab == 1}" ng-click="active_tab = 1"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: active_tab == 2}" ng-click="active_tab = 2"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li> 
        <li ng-class="{active: active_tab == 3}" ng-click="active_tab = 3"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Selected Tab: {{ active_tab }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- end uib-collapse -->
  </nav> <!-- end nav -->
<uib-tabset active="active_tab">
  <ng-controller ng-controller="test_controller1">
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="tab 1">1: {{ tab1_content }}</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="tab 2">2: {{ tab2_content }}</uib-tab>
  </ng-controller>
  <ng-controller ng-controller="test_controller2">
    <uib-tab index="3" heading="tab 3">3: {{ tab3_content }}</uib-tab>
  </ng-controller>
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: What s your question really I am bit confused .. could add somethig ? whats breaking it seems to work on

Comment: The tab switching no longer works, even though active_tab seems to change as each nav link is clicked.

Comment: Can you post the code that actually doesn't work? The plunker doesn't make use of ng-include, so no one understands how to duplicate the problem. As an aside, Since you are already using Angular 1.6.5 I would highly recommend you refactor and eliminate the use of ng-include in favor of using components.

Comment: In the plunker it seems to work .. only update code with non working plunker

Comment: The second plunker link has the not-working ng-include code... but the code itself hasn't changed, just how it loads through the template instead of on the main document... https://plnkr.co/edit/Lbh2Pw2wiZAS6oZTwX47?p=preview